# Iterating over Xml Node

Tags: java

I am iterating over an XML and the expected output is to form a Binary tree. My XML is

```xml
<SUB>
    <IN>
        <Number>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <ID>2</ID>
        </Number>
    </IN>
</SUB>
```

So the expected ouput is SUB as parent node and subsequently the child nodes.While I am trying to iterate over SUB node its giving me 5 values..3 values as #text..?

I need to add IN as left node.

Comment: Can you explain clearly?

Comment: If u follow my XML above..I need to form a Binary tree from it which has SUB as uts parent node..IN as its Left Node and subsequently ID as its sub node...and den form a INFIX expression from it

Comment: the Expression would be (IN condition)SUB..sumthing lyk dis

Comment: are you using any framework like JXAB to parse the xml?

Answer (score 0):

While iterating over the xml you need to check whether the node type of that node is of type Element as
           exampleNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
 if the above condition is true then only enter so it will return you 2 values instead of 5.

Comment: Hi,Can you please help me in building the whole tree..I have added one element..and dis should be the parent node for my next sub child..But when I am doing this..It is saying node to string conversion is not possible

Comment: And how do i upvoye it?

Comment: have you tried to use getTextContent() method of the node. You can get the text content by this method.

Comment: by clicking the up button on the left side having tooltip(answer is useful)

Comment: Hi,I tried using it..if i use getTextContent() it will give me the further values lyk the values of ID

Answer (score 0):

It's common to find the values like #text or #comment.

This is what I use to avoid those:

```
if (node.getNodeName().equals("#text")|| node.getNodeName().equals("#comment")) continue;
```

And also notice to cast the `Node` to `Element` AFTER doing that check. Or you will try to cast an #text to `Element` and an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Hi,Can you please help me in building the whole tree..I have added one element..and dis should be the parent node for my next sub child..But when I am doing this..It is saying node to string conversion is not possible –

Comment: go ahead, i'll give a try.

Comment: whr shall i pasteit..?

Comment: I have added a comment on the line where I am getting the error

Comment: did u had a look at it..?